# patterns vs. guards: otherwise does not match?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, guard-clause

The following two functions behave differently when given an empty string:

```
guardMatch l@(x:xs) 
    | x == '-'        = "negative " ++ xs
    | otherwise       = l

patternMatch ('-':xs) = "negative " ++ xs
patternMatch l        = l
```

Here my output:

```
*Main> guardMatch ""
"*** Exception: matching.hs:(1,1)-(3,20): Non-exhaustive patterns in function guardMatch

*Main> patternMatch ""
""
```

*Question*: why does not the 'otherwise' close catch the empty string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `otherwise` is within the scope of the pattern `l@(x:xs)`, which can only match a non-empty string.  It might help to see what this (effectively) translates to internally:

```
guardMatch   l = case l of
                   (x  :xs) -> if x == '-' then "negative " ++ xs else l
patternMatch l = case l of
                   ('-':xs) ->                  "negative " ++ xs
                   _        ->                                         l
```

(Actually, I think the `if` is translated to a `case` + guard instead of the other way around.)

Comment: IIRC the `if` is translated as you say.

Answer (score 9):

A guard is always evaluated *after* the pattern. This is - the guard is tried iff the pattern succeeds. In your case, the pattern `(x:xs)` excludes the empty string, so the guards are not even tried, as the pattern fails.

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers are totally right of course, but here's another way to think about it: What if you had written this?

```
guardMatch l@(x:xs) 
    | x == '-'        = "negative " ++ xs
    | otherwise       = [x]
```

What would you expect `guardMatch ""` to be?

Comment: Good point! As the above answers taught me, (x:xs) pattern matches only non empty lists.